# How do I change the link preview text for a website using HTML, CSS, etc?

Tags: html, css, facebook

How do I change the link preview text for a website using HTML, CSS, etc? In particular, I'm referring to the text in the link box on Facebook.

Comment: Do you mean the text that appears when you hover over a link?

Comment: Are you referring to the `title` attribute?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup

Answer (score 1):

You need to use open graph meta tag properties. See Facebook's developer guidelines for examples.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup